# CartoDB adjusting the style of the layer toggle function

Tags: carto, layers, function

The layer names are cut off in the toggle layer function. Is it possible to adjsut the font size or the length of the layer function box so text is not cut off?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware this is not possible in the CartoDB editor. It would be possible to change the width or font in CSS if you're using CartoDB.js. In that case apply your styling to div.cartodb-layer-selector-box.